# Can I position the post thumbnail right next to the post in WordPress? (Theming)

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to position my post thumbnail next to the post itself. Furthermore, I'd like to include some responsive-breakpoints, so that in mobile view the thumbnail is on top of the post. I'd like to work with the bootstrap framework. Any help is appreciated :)

```
<div class="container-fluid the_loop">
    <div class="col-4">
        <?php while ( $wpb_all_query->have_posts() ) : $wpb_all_query->the_post(); ?>
        <img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url("post_image");?>" alt="img-fluid">
    </div>
    <div class="col-8">
        <h2 id="title" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
           <?php the_title(); ?>
        </h2>
        <p id="the_date"><?php the_date(); ?></p>
        <p id="the_content"><?php the_content(); ?></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's so many ways of doing what you are trying to do, the best will be giving the content div a 70% width and the thumbnail div a 30% width;

by doing this you will be making sure each div has it's own width, and they will be displayed beside each other.

and in your case, when you do the mobile break point the thumbnail div is already above the content div so when you give the thumbnail a wider width let's say 100% it will be displayed above the content.

the other solution is to look at [this page](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/examples/blog/), it has what you are searching for with in depth details